# Continuous function problem in equality

Tags: calculus

If there is f in [a, b] such us f(a) =f(b)=0,f continuous and can be derivated in(a, b) then prove that f'(x) - kf(x) =0 for every k in R, has one root in(a, b). I can imagine it like a cycle that has R = ε and R can grow, with center (x) moving on δ between in(a, b),but this is not proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the function $g(x)=e^{-kx}f(x)$ and apply to it Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Done it and found f'(x) - kx/ef(x) =0.Thanks I did t notice it was answered.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).